# How to take weekdays using sql query?

Tags: sql

I have 2 days

```
Date_from 01/03/2011 
Date_to   15/03/2011
```

How to take special week days (Monday, Tuesday and Friday ) from above two date range?

I need output like below

```
Date_From   Date_To    
01/03/2011  01/03/2011  'Tuesday
04/03/2011  04/03/2011  'Friday
07/03/2011  08/03/2011  'Monday and Tuesday
11/03/2011  11/03/2011  'Friday
14/03/2011  15/03/2011  'Monday and Tuesday
```

Comment: What RDBMS is this for? And you should accept some answers to your previous questions. Has this (very similar) question been answered satisfactorily for example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357497/how-to-display-weekdays-from-below-two-days-monday-and-friday

Comment: +1, for Martin.  The answer for this question is in the answers for the nearly identical question you asked 30 minutes ago.  Please read the FAQs before posting any more questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for SQL Server do this:

```
SELECT DATENAME(dw, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH    wd (d) AS
        (
        SELECT  0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  d + 1
        FROM    wd
        WHERE   d < 6
        )
SELECT  d.date_from,
        (
        SELECT  DATENAME(w, DATEADD(d, d, date_from))  + ' ' AS [text()]
        FROM    wd
        WHERE   DATEPART(w, DATEADD(d, d, date_from)) IN (2, 5, 6)
                AND DATEADD(d, d, date_from) <= date_to
        FOR XML PATH('')
        )
FROM    dates d
```

Answer (score 1):

use [WEEKDAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) or [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)