# Display Data week wise from Table(First Entry) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a Table like :

I am Trying like this (Query):

```
   --count of appointment ( day )   


 select DATENAME(WEEKDAY,AppDate) as Appointment,con.DrCode,doc.Doctor,con.AppDate,
  COUNT(con.AppDate)  as Appointment   from Consultation as con inner join DoctorMaster as doc on con.DrCode=doc.id where con.DrCode='2'
  GROUP BY CAST(AppDate AS DATE),con.DrCode,doc.Doctor,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,AppDate)


--count of appointment ( Week )


select con.DrCode,doc.Doctor,COUNT(con.AppDate) as Appointment from
Consultation as con inner join DoctorMaster as doc on con.DrCode=doc.id   where con.DrCode='2'
and (AppDate > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) and AppDate < GETDATE()-1)
group by DATEPART(wk,AppDate),con.DrCode,doc.Doctor
```

count of appointment Week  Wise Display like:

```
    Dr     Doctor     Appointment
    2    Kamal Goyal    3
    2    Kamal Goyal    17
    2    Kamal Goyal    14
    2    Kamal Goyal    8
    2    Kamal Goyal    10
    2    Kamal Goyal    1
```

But i want to Display with Day Wise:

```
Day     Dr     Doctor     Appointment
sun     2    Kamal Goyal    3
mon     2    Kamal Goyal    Null
tues    2    Kamal Goyal    Null
wed     2    Kamal Goyal    8
thus    2    Kamal Goyal    Null
fri     2    Kamal Goyal    1
sat     2    Kamal Goyal    1
```

Comment: properly clear what you want & what your output

Comment: whats wrong with first query ? Try aliasing first column in result set as day instead of `appointment`, as you have aliased 2 columns with same name

Comment: @SyedNasrulIslamAnam I am getting the output as Dr. 'Kamal Goyal' has 3 appointment in a first week and 17 in second week..but i want fetch data like Dr. 'Kamal Goyal' has 3 appointment and  first appointment  is on sun second is 'wed' and in case 'dr; have no any appointment  then show blank .is this possible?

Comment: @aparnarai this linkcan help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358097/how-to-take-weekdays-using-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` clause should describe each row you want in the result set -- the distinct values of the `GROUP BY` keys define each row.

So, remove `AppDate` from the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.

```
select datename(weekday, AppDate) as Appointment, 
       con.DrCode, doc.Doctor,
       COUNT(con.AppDate) as Appointment
from Consultation con inner join
     DoctorMasterdoc
     on con.DrCode = doc.id
where con.DrCode = 2
group by datename(weekday, AppDate), con.DrCode, doc.Doctor;
```

Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Use recursive CTE for date range with days and then bind your result with Appointment date.